# presentViewControllerAnimated results in black screen after dismissViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

Within this ViewController I am working with I have a private `UIImagePickerController` declared in the `@interface`

> @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

After some event the following method is called

```
- (void)showPhotoLibrary {
    if(!self.imagePickerController) {
        self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }

        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Later after whichever action the user takes (selecting an image or cancel) the following is called:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now here is my problem. The first time through this code everything works as expected. The UIImagePickerController is displayed correctly and dismissed correctly. On the second execution of this code a black screen is presented instead of the expected UiImagePickerController.

I have been looking on stackoverflow and other places online and have been unable to figure this out.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/
here in this link see the first video `A look inside present viewcontrollers`
u will get the solution

Comment: I downloaded an example of UIImagePickerController from Apple and it looks like they initialize the picker controller each time before they show it.
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ... other initialization code ...
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];